# XeLaTeX exit codes

Tags: tex-core, xetex

I'm running XeLaTeX from a shell script and would like to check for exit codes, to see if an error was encountered during processing.

So I'm looking for a list of possible exit codes. I've checked the documentation and googled quite extensively but can't find such a list.

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure it will support exit codes. I assume you've tried  `XeLaTex --help` and `strings /path/to/XeLaTex`?  Try doing `XeLaTex .. args_as_needed ... NONEXISTANTFILE ; echo $?` to see if it catches that simple error. If that reports an error, then see what error code is returned if you give it a deliberately malformed document. Depending on your need, that may be enough. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. --help did not give any info on return codes. The echo $ method helped, hadn't thought of that. So far I gathered that return code 0 means no (significant) errors, 1 means problems.

Comment: yes, that's right. You seldom see a return code from an application higher than 3 or 4 (all non-zeros mean some kind of error). You can build tests like `if XLateX ... args .. File file2...` ; then echo everything OK ; else echo error processing file ; fi` OR xLatext...args... ; rc=$? ; case ${rc} in 0) echo OK ;; * ) echo got error code ${rc} ;; esac`  Got to go. Good luck.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682411/xelatex-exit-codes?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

There's no support for exit codes different from 0 or 1, I'm afraid.

The presence of warnings, as opposed to errors, can be checked for with the `texloganalyser` script.